# Get NSManagedObject array from UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have UITableViewController filled from the base through NSFetchedResultsController. The view have save button. I select items from the tableView by checking button. I need results in another view. What is the best way to transmit checked items?
I am thinking about of array NSManagedObject's. So in another view I would call to [managedObject valueForKey:@"Name"]; Is it correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remember NSManagedObjects. They are easily accesible from NSFetchedResultsController object. Just remember in array NSIndexPaths of selected objects. Then you could access those objects in similar way:

```
MyObject *object = (MyObject *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:
[anArray objectAtIndex:index]];
```